# Change response cache header for a request

Tags: javascript, response, cache-control, no-cache

I'm working on a web app that uses an external api where I don't have any control on the **response cache options**. The endpoint gives **cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate**, where I need to make response storable and cachable during the user's session or for a short known period of time, so the user doesn't have to wait the response from the api every time. Is there any possible solution for my problem?

Comment: Save the contents in a variable...? If you need persistent storage, use the [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use SessionStorage for storing data for a browser session. More on this you can read [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)